# SAML Integration in Java

Tags: java, spring, saml

I am working on a project where I have to do the SAML implementation and I have some doubts:

1. What is the metadata file and how is it useful in SAML ?
2. How does SAML makes sure that the response coming from the IdP is not changed by a malicious user in the middle of the transit ? to authenticate a malicious user.
3. [Here is the list](https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/) of SAML xml schemas available. How would I use it to produce a mock SAML request in java ?

Comment: 2) SAML assertion is signed by the identity provider and the service provider validates the signature using the public key of the service provider.

Answer (score 1):

I will extend answer of Bartosz.  I will assume that you want to implement a service provider and use SAML WebSSO profile.

> What is the metadata file and how is it useful in SAML ?

the metadata allow automated import of IdP or SP information ( their EntityID, endpoints, certificate, suported bindings)

> How does SAML makes sure that the response coming 
>   from the IdP is not changed by a malicious user in the 
>   middle of the transit ? to authenticate a malicious user.

This is a very important part. Basicaly - the data are signed by the issuer's private key. There are two options - the whole 
message is signed or assertions are signed (or both). The service provider absolutely **MUST** check issuer's id (EntityID), validity time and signature. Here I suggest you to use a mature framework (spring-security or OpenSAML) and as well check security forums of the used version, as some versions are vulnerable to "signature injection" attacks.

> Here is the list of SAML xml schemas available
>   . How would I use it to produce a mock SAML
>    request in java ?

definitely you should understand the SAML authentication flow and essages passed and different options (e.g. redirect binding uses deflated and encoded messages, post binding only encoded)

I suggest you to have a look at ssocircle.com , they have public IdP you could use for testing and tools to decode the saml messages. You cannot simply mock the messages as they have limited validity in time. What I did for development and testing - I installed the simpleSAMLphp, that is a simple and effective php tool to configure a SAML IdP or SP.

Comment: some questions about the metadata file.
1) to integrate SAML do i need metadata file for both SP and IdP ?
2) Do i manually create the metadata file ?
3) Can you simply explain what entityID is ?

Comment: 1. You do not need any metadata file as mandatory, IdP needs information about SP (EntityID, endpoint, certificate (optional) and the SP needs information about IdP (EntityID, endpoints, certificate) 2, you can, or you can export metadata if you have a service for it 3. Every party (IdP, each SP) needs its identifier. That's it. Just an identifier. In theory it can be any string, however we advice to have it in form of URL (e.g. to distinguish different environment, stages, ...)

Comment: (might be a stupid question)what is the difference between SAML assertions and request/response ? is assertion like an umberalla name for request and response ?

Comment: it looks like boring reading, but you really should read the spec. Assertion is a "claim" or any data that IdP sends to SP in the SAML response. Usually it can be considered as a subject's (user's) attribute. SAML Req is a message sent from SP to IdP (request to logon), response is SAMLResponse from IdP to SP (with subject, assertions and signature). Req/Resp has different context with single logout, but first you shall understand step 1

Comment: So in my case I am having a web portal as the SP and I am trying to implement an SSO using SAML to an IdP of my company. I already have a login system in place which uses database to retrieve user data to log them in. But for the project I want to remove the login and have SAML implemented so when the user clicks on the login link or sumthing they are logged in with SSO. 1) What are the steps i could take to start this process ? 2) I cant get my head around how the assertions work. How do I create a authnrequest using java ?

Comment: 1 - a) send an authentication request to IdP, b) IdP can send a SAMLResponse even without any request (IdP-initiated SSO). 2) check one of the libraries (e.g. OpenSAML or spring-security), there's a step by step documentation. REALLY read it, try it, fail, try again. There's a lot to read and its out of scope of this question

Comment: @computerscientist123 what I sugget you google a little around for "SAML SSO flow", once you understand the flow, then choose a library you will use (OpenSAML or Spring Security SAML whatever fits your needs), start with a sample and then ask concrete questions. Usually IdP should help you to onboard (have some documentation)

Comment: Another final question ... once the IdP sends a response to the browser with a SAML token(an assertion xml format im guessing) it is stored in the user's browser cookie/session right ?(correct me if I am wrong). Is there a way that can be used to retrieve the information of the saml token from the cookie ? do i need to java code to do that ? or can you send me a link to webpage thats got code which does this please ?. Thanks


[Link](https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml/blob/master/samples/java-saml-tookit-jspsample/src/main/webapp/acs.jsp)

does this jsp file show how to do it ?

Comment: the user posts the SAMLResponse (from IdP) to the SP's ACS (assertion consumer service), where the SAMLResponse xml is validated and user identity is assumed. The SP auhenticates the user based on the information (assertions/claims) in the response. Then the SAML response is no longer needed. It is too big to fit in a cookie and pass it along every request. The session is application specific (cookie, application token, whatever). Indeed onelogin has as well a nice and simple library (though not supporting all options, but usable for most of the cases)

Comment: what are the options that the onelogin library does not use ?

Comment: I believe it lacked (a few years ago) support for Artifact binding, but for 99.999% you won't need that. While it supports POST and Redirect SSO binding, you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I have succesfully used http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/ for that porupose. It uses basic concepts of spring security and adds support for SAML.

**metadata file and how is it useful in SAML?**

Metadata contains basic information about Service Provider or Identity provider. For examples see
https://www.samltool.com/sp_metadata.php
https://www.samltool.com/idp_metadata.php

**How does SAML makes sure that the response coming from the IdP is not changed by a malicious user in the middle of the transit ?**

SAML assertions are signed by private key. After being received they are verified (using public key). Because private key is secret, nobody will be able to modify SAML document and sign it.

**How would I use it to produce a mock SAML request in java ?**

For mock SAML request you could just POST hard-coded XML document (SAML assertion). For this approach to work you need following changes
1) update timestamp in that mock document
2) configure Spring SAML to work with unsiged SAML assertions. This solution is suitable only for development.

Another option is described in https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/chapter-idp-guide.html#chapter-idp-guide-adfs-test (use Spring SAML sample application)

Comment: I would try to enforce the signature validation from beginning, even when it looks like more struggle. I've seen a few apps going to production without any ticket validation :/

Comment: Something about the signing assertions by private key ....How do I create a private key ? how do I sign the assertions ? (I dont mind even if the answer us quite long. thanks)

Comment: IdP needs to sign the assertion, the SP just validates the signature based on the configured certificate. Usually the library does it for you, the IdP must give you its public certificate.